Why are we using KL divergence over cross entropy?
I read this question
Why do we use Kullback-Leibler divergence rather than cross entropy in the t-SNE objective function?
and I cannot fully understand the answer.
If we're using KL divergence for the loss, doesn't it have the same effect to using cross entropy? When KL divergence is large, cross entropy is large, and vice versa. The amount of change of two are not that different, too. In addition, the KL divergence has more terms to compute, the entropy.
From this point of view, I cannot find a reason to use KL divergence instead of cross entorpy.
Can anyone help me?
(+ If KL divergence is really better than cross entropy (for loss function), I'm also curious about why some tasks are still using cross entropy)

I don't see how this question is different from the original one cited, and I don't think the way CrossValidated works allows for question of the kind "I don't understand the answer given elsewhere, so I ask what it means as a new question", sorry.

Maybe somebody who sees this and knows how to explain this in a different way can add another answer there.

By the way, from the answer there: "So, from the perspective of the optimization problem, minimizing the KL divergence and minimizing the cross entropy are equivalent."
